# JavaScript API - Why is only one JSON key/vaule pair being displayed?

Tags: javascript, json, api, openweathermap

I am testing APIs on Github pages. I was able to consume the Openweather.org API. The full JSON data is viewable in the browser but only one key/value pair, "description", will show up on my page. I tried adding three div tags to HTML, using a colon between weather and the key I want to render and I have tried using just one dot. I have googled this issue but have not found anything that relates to my project.

Also, note that I have commented out two variables, **const t** and **const m** because they make the program fail. I was trying to copy the format of **const p**. Any guidance would be appreciated!!

**Here is the JSON weather data:**

```
{
    coord: {
        lon: -0.13,
        lat: 51.51
    },
    weather: [
        {
            id: 701,
            main: "Mist",
            description: "mist",
            icon: "50n"
        }
    ],
    base: "stations",
    main: {
        temp: 278.61,
        pressure: 1024,
        humidity: 81,
        temp_min: 276.15,
        temp_max: 280.15
    },
    visibility: 10000,
    wind: {
        speed: 3.1,
        deg: 100
    },
    clouds: {
        all: 20
    },
    dt: 1544552400,
    sys: {
        type: 1,
        id: 1414,
        message: 0.0033,
        country: "GB",
        sunrise: 1544515001,
        sunset: 1544543482
    },
    id: 2643743,
    name: "London",
    cod: 200
}
```

**Here is my JavaScript:**

```
//added strict mode to address following error message, "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0."   'use strict';

const app = document.getElementById("root");

//add API related image
const weather = document.createElement("img");
weather.src = "weather.jpg";

const container = document.createElement("div");
container.setAttribute("class", "container");

//method to append the logo image and container div to the app root.
app.appendChild(weather);
app.appendChild(container);

// Create a request variable and assign a new XMLHttpRequest object to it.
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Open a new connection, using the GET request on the URL endpoint
request.open("GET", "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&APPID=14d276f4fe655e659ec92149c7cebbec", true);

request.onload = function () {    

    // Begin accessing JSON data here

    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
      if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        data.weather.forEach(weather => {
          const card = document.createElement("div");
          card.setAttribute("class", "card");
          const h1 = document.createElement("h1");
          h1.textContent = weather.title;

          const p = document.createElement("p");
          weather.description = weather.description.substring(0, 300);
          p.textContent = `${weather.description}...`;

          /*const m = document.createElement("p");
          weather.main = weather.main.substring(0, 300);
          m.textContent = `${weather.main}...`;

          const t = document.createElement("p");
          weather.main.temp = weather.main.temp;
          t.textContent = `${weather.main.temp}...`; */

          // Append the cards to the container element
          container.appendChild(card);

          // Each card will contain an h1 and a p    
          card.appendChild(h1);
          card.appendChild(p);
        });
      } else {
        const errorMessage = document.createElement("marquee");
        errorMessage.textContent = `Hug it, it's not working!`;
        app.appendChild(errorMessage);
      }
    }
    // send request
    request.send();
```

**Here is the HTML**:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">

   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

   <title>API Testing</title>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700" 
   rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <div id="root"></div>
     <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Here is the CSS:**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

html {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #666;
  background: #F6F6F6;
}

#root {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.5rem 2.5rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #fbc2eb 0%, #a6c1ee 100%);
  margin: 0 0 2rem 0;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: white;
}

p,t {
  padding: 0 2.5rem 2.5rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  margin: 1rem;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .2s linear;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 2px 8px 45px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  transform: translate3D(0, -2px, 0);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .card {
    flex: 1 1 calc(50% - 2rem);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .card {
    flex: 1 1 calc(33% - 2rem);
  }
}

.card:nth-child(2n) h1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #84fab0 0%, #8fd3f4 100%);
}

.card:nth-child(4n) h1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #ff9a9e 0%, #fecfef 100%);
}

.card:nth-child(5n) h1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #ffc3a0 0%, #ffafbd 100%);
}
```

Comment: I am unclear as to what problem you are experiencing. I see an error in your example javascript about parsing the result from your API call. Is that the issue you are talking about? Or something else entirely? `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0." `

Comment: @RyanWilson That was an error message I had solved last week. I added that in the comments to remind myself why I used strict mode. Currently there should not be any error messages.

Comment: Then what is the problem?

Comment: @RyanWilson Here is what you see on my Github page: [link] https://codeduchess.github.io/  You currenlty only see the description: "mist," I want to see more data, i.e. like the temp, city, etc. So, I added the const t for temp, etc, but it does not show up. Does that make sense?

Comment: I created a js fiddle for you, I can work with that to try and help you with this: (https://jsfiddle.net/ep84so9m/1/)

Comment: @RyanWilson Thanks!! I have been meaning to try JSFiddle out.

Comment: I found a couple of issues, I updated the fiddle to this (https://jsfiddle.net/ep84so9m/2/) and it appears to be doing what you want. One issue was where you went to get the temp, temp is a property of the object main which is a property of data, not the weather object, you are iterating the weather array which only contains value for properties id, main, description and icon.

Comment: @RyanWilson You got there at the same time I did. He's trying to access all the properties within the weather loop.

Comment: @RyanGibbs Good eyes sir. Glad you joined in the assist.

Comment: @Dana Did any of what i put on that jsfiddle help you? Does my explanation make sense to you about how you are iterating the weather objects and that some of the property values you want are not part of those weather objects??

Comment: @RyanWilson I was just comparing the documents to see what changes you made and I thought I had implemented them all -- but now I am getting that darn data.forEach error again - God I love that one! So, I will go back and compare them again. I do not understand why I cannot access all the weather data when JSON has displayed it on the browser.

Comment: @Dana I think maybe you should read up on JSON and how it is formatted, it seems you may be a bit confused on that topic.

Comment: @RyanWilson I just copied and pasted your JSFIddle -- thinking I have stared at this so long that I am missing something. It still only shows "mist." I do not understand what is going on. . .time for a break.

Comment: @RyanWilson Good idea. I will do that. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @Dana Make sure you use the updated fiddle at url (https://jsfiddle.net/ep84so9m/2/) the first one I added only showed mist.. I can try to help you more if you want, just message me and I'll respond when I see it, or if you need to reach me outside of SO, I can provide you with contact info

Comment: @RyanWilson Thanks, Ryan, I think I get it now! Have a great day!

Comment: @Dana you too. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

**The Problem:**

As discussed by Ryan Wilson, the problem you're seeing is that you're trying to access parameters that are not in the weather property of your JSON while you're looping through the weather property. To help you understand this, consider the following JSON (Truncated from the API you're using):

```
data = {
    weather: [
                {
                    id: 721,
                    main: "Haze",
                    description: "haze",
                    icon: "50n"
                },
                {
                    id: 300,
                    main: "Drizzle",
                    description: "light intensity drizzle",
                    icon: "09n"
                },
                {
                    id: 701,
                    main: "Mist",
                    description: "mist",
                    icon: "50n"
                }
            ],
    base: "stations",
    main: {
                temp: 278.37,
                pressure: 1023,
                humidity: 87,
                temp_min: 276.15,
                temp_max: 280.15
           }
    id: 2643743,
    name: "London",
    cod: 200
};
```

There are multiple levels to this JSON object. If I want to access the mist weather, I would have to use data.weather[2].main, which would return "Mist". This is because I'm grabbing the property 'main' from the third item in the weather array.

Now, if I were to try to get the 'temp' by using data.weather[2].main.temp, it would not return anything because there is no 'temp' property under the third weather object. There is, however, a temp property under the main object at the data object's root. To access that, you would need to be using data.main.temp.

**How does this apply to your code?**

If you look at your code, you loop through the data.weather array using:

```
data.weather.forEach(weather => {
    //...
});
```

For each iteration of that block, the variable 'weather' will equal one of the objects in the data.weather array. So if you were to use:

```
data.weather.forEach(weather => {
    console.log(weather.main);
});
```

You would get 'Haze', then 'Drizzle', then 'Mist'. (Based on the JSON I've shown above).

I believe you had that much figured out, but then you attempted to get the temperature by using weather.main.temp, which is not a valid parameter. You would instead have to use data.main.temp.

I hope that clears up JSON a little for you.

**The Real Answer:**

The real answer to your question "Why is it only showing one key value pair?" doesn't actually have anything to do with what I said above. If you were to look at the JSON that API was sending when you posted the question, you'd have seen that there was only one object in the weather array. As of this writing there are three. Your code will only create as many cards as there are items in the weather array.

Be sure to refer to Ryan Wilson's JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ep84so9m/2/
He's modified your code to do what it appears your were after.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nice explanation. Well thought out and explained. +1

Comment: @Ryan Gibbs Thanks, Ryan, that helps a lot! One quick question.  Why do you need to use "data" for the temp but not for the description? See below: temp.textContent = `${data.main.temp}...`;  describe.textContent = `${weather.description}...`; Seems like it should be data.weather.description as well.

Comment: Because 'weather' is a local variable inside your forEach loop that equates to data.weather. You could do this too: data.weather.forEach(myVarName=> {
    console.log(myVarName.main);
});